# ZEND execute/call function stored in string

Tags: zend-framework, function, call

i have a problem with calling a function which name is a string.

I made few helpers which i want to echo in my phtml file like this:

```
echo $this->EditProfile();
echo $this->ViewProfile();
```

The EditProfile() and ViewProfile() are names of the View Helpers which i created and i'm calling them in view. And this method is working fine. But when i want dynamicly call a function by name stored in database im trying to do this in this way:

im getting the names of helpers from database and store them into array and then trying to display them in foreach.

```
foreach ($this->modules as $key => $module)
    {   
echo  $this->$module['name'];
    }
```

the variable

```
$module['name']
```

contains a valid name of Helper which i want to call in phtml file (checked with Zend_debug::dump() and with just an echo $module['name'] in foeach and id display it properly... but this echo its not working and not calling the View Helper, nothing is displayed

when i try eval or call_user_func too nothing is displayed too... How can i do this in foreach or other loop?

Comment: What is stored in `$module['name']`? Something like string `'EditProfile'` or `'EditProfile()'`? The parentheses are necessary to trigger the view-helper plugin mechanism. Without them, they would refer to only variables in the view, which are presumably empty.

Answer (score 0):

ok solved it myself :)
dont know is this solution properly but its actually working ;)

instead call_user_func i mentioned that magical function __call is same as call_user_func_array

so i edited code like this below

```
foreach ($this->modules as $key => $module)
{
$this->__call($module['name'],array(null));
}
```

in this case array is null cause none parameters are passed to function. If in my helper ill need parameters ill pass them in this array in future.
And this solution works fine for me :)

If someone have better solution please post it here and share your opinion ;)
regards
Darek

Comment: Congrats on the solution! When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success. Cheers~